# Authentication Key in Azure App registration?

Tags: azure, azure-service-principal

How to find Authentication Key in Azure App registration? Where to find/create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Authentication key has been renamed to client secret. You can create client secret in your App.
[image]